# How to: C# source with syntax highlighting on PowerPoint slides

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, powerpoint

I would like to show some C# source code in a PowerPoint presentation. But how can I copy the code ***including the syntax highlighting*** onto the slides? I could make screenshots, but that has some drawbacks (ugly, font size, unmaintainable). Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 50):

1. copy the code from Visual Studio to PowerPoint
2. choose "keep original formatting" on the Paste Options icon

Comment: Embarassingly I totally missed that feature... ;) Unfortunately, however, the code is randomly colored and needs to be fixed with a load of extra work.

Comment: For some reason I only have the option to paste RTF or unformatted.  RTF does not preserve black text.

Comment: Oh my god... any idea how many times I've looked for a way to do this!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't preserve the original font this way. I tend to use Krogue2's solution using "Paste Special (CTRL+ALT+V)" and then "Formatted Text (RTF)"

Comment: +1 - this doesn't keep the formatting - at least not in PPT 2010.  Paste Special with HTML worked well for me.

Comment: FYI, this also works on a Mac when the code (C++ in my case) was copied from XCode (tested with PowerPoint 2011 and XCode 4.6.3)

Comment: When I attempt this from Visual Studio 2013 into PowerPoint 2010, all line breaks are missing, effectively writing all the code as a single, very wide line. If I select *Keep text only*, the line breaks are preserved, but then I lose the formatting :(

Answer (score 29):

If I copy the code from Visual Studio directly into PowerPoint, using Paste Special (and picking RTF), it only does *some* of the formatting.
Here is how I got it to do all the formatting.

1. Copy the code in Visual Studio.   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
2. Open a new Word document and do a paste.   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
3. Re-select the code in Word and copy it again.  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
4. In PowerPoint, do a Paste Special, as "HTML Format".  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Answer (score 13):

"Paste Special" (Ctrl+Alt+V) will do it. This option is available in different places depending on your version of PowerPoint.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work at all, at least not in the ordinary text boxes. BTW, we are using Office 2003. Maybe this is new in the 2007 version?

Answer (score 8):

In [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) 6.9.2 or higher, right click the text and select `Plugin Commands` and `Copy Text with Syntax Highlighting`.

Comment: This is great alternative when you don't want to buy/install visual studio just to prepare a slide show.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work. PowerPoint 2016 and notepad ++ 7.1.

Answer (score 7):

I accept all of the answers posted.

I have found a more presentable way of sharing the code in ppt, which will look elegant in presentation.

use https://carbon.now.sh/ which is free and open source, add your code, do customizations and then export it to add it in ppt.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. in PPT, click "Insert" -> "Object" -> "Create New" -> "Microsoft Word Document"
2. Copy your code to the newly created object in PPT slides,
3. You will see the formatting and highlight now.

Answer (score 3):

Copy and paste the code to WordPad, then copy from word pad to wherever you want and keep original formatting[image: keepOriginalFormatting]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Live Writer with the [Insert Code](http://insertcode.codeplex.com/) plugin to "write" the C# code and syntax highlight it.  This should be copy and pastable directly into PowerPoint, since it's inlines all of the syntax highlighting using styling elements.